# Modulus of convexity

Tags: convex-analysis

I am reading a proof in a textbook and the author uses an assumption of "convexity modulus" for a function $l$ which states:

$$
l(u)+l(v)-l\left(\frac{u+v}{2}\right) \geq C |u-v|^2
$$

for some $C > 0$.

Is this standard terminology?

Comment: To check if it holds for $l(u)=u^2$ is straightforward. About the *standard terminology*, I have never heard of the *convexity modulus* or *midpoint-convexity modulus*, but it is a fairly natural generalization of $\frac{f(u)-f(v)}{|u-v|}$.